# ASP Server Controls If SQL Field is Populated

Tags: asp.net, sql, eval, servercontrols

I am trying to figure out how I can use ASP Server Control tags to determine if the field I am evaluating is return anything if not then it needs to check another field that has data in it. I have the two statements below, and I was wondering How can I combine them so that if the CID doesn't exist then it looks and the EID. How can I accomplish this?

```
<%# Eval("CID", "us.aspx?id={0}") %>
<%# Eval("EID", "ei.aspx?id={0}") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean if `Eval("CID")` is null, then show `EID` or show the `CID`? You could try:

```
<%# (Eval("CID") == null) ? Eval("EID", "ei.aspx?id={0}") : Eval("CID", "us.aspx?id={0}") %>
```

Comment: do you know what exactly these commands are called in aspx pages? Where can I read more about these, I have no idea if I used the correct name, but I would like to find out more about them. Things like the `<%# %> <% %> <%$ %>`

Comment: @atrljoe: The `?:` is called a ternary operator. You can read more [about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). More about [C# Operators here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx). More about [inline ASP.NET tags here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In VB you can accomplish this by using the following

```
<%# IIF(IsDBNULL("CID"), "ei.aspx?id={" & Eval("EID") & "}", "us.aspx?id={" & Eval("CID") & "}")
```

You may want to use IsNothing in place of IsDBNull depending on your situation.